# How to access other state/property value in new state prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to access the value of state/property in new state prop. Actually I have already state property where I am storing value of `Item=5` and I create `UrlParam` Where I am storing URL but I need `Item` numeric value in URL property. I am new to React , Somebody please help me how to do this ?

I am not getting number value currently I am getting string. You may see in attachment .

**Code**

```
    this.state={    
    Item : 5,
    Skip:0,
    urlParams:'http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=Item&&filter[skip]=Skip'
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using interpolation (`{Skip}` or `{this.state.Skip}`)? I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... could you clarify and include a larger code sample, including the components you are working on?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173610/can-a-javascript-object-property-refer-to-another-property-of-the-same-object

Comment: @GarrettMotzner , I updated my question , Please have a look to given attachment . Thanks

Comment: @isherwood Actually I am getting string value .

Comment: I'm assuming your code sample is in the constructor? because outside of the constructor, it is a bad idea to do `this.state=` or modify the state (like `this.state.foo=` or similar).

Comment: Yes , It inside in constructor

Answer (score 2):

Set it after.

```
this.state={    
    Item : 5,
    Skip:0,
    urlParams:''
}

this.setState({ urlParams: 'http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=' + this.state.Item + '&filter[skip]=' + this.state.Skip })
```

OR

```
this.setState({ urlParams: `http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${this.state.Item}&filter[skip]=${this.state.Skip}` })
```

You could also create functions to update the url anytime the Item or Skip value changes

```
updateItem(newValue) {
   this.setState({ 
      Item: newValue, 
      urlParams: `http://localhost:8001/parties?filter[limit]=${newValue}&filter[skip]=${this.state.Skip}`
   })
}
```

Comment: I want to use it in state . not outside . Could you please help

Comment: If you already know the values OR are passing them as variables to set  your initial state you can use the same to set the url.

Comment: I am getting Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to use the `Item` state in your `urlParams` state. This cannot be done in the state declaration without using some sort of helper function, so a better alternative is to call `setState()` in order to declare `urlParams` after the fact.

In a React component, this may look something like:

```js
state = {
  Item: 5,
  Skip: 0,
  urlParams: "",
}

componentDidMount() {

  ...

  this.setState((prevState) => { 
    urlParams: `filter[limit]=${prevState.Item}&&filter[skip]=${prevState.Stem}`
  }

  ...

}
```

It may seem like a hastle if you're new to React, but it's the best way to go since you should never modify state directly.

```js
// good
this.setState((prevState) => ...)

// bad
this.state.urlParams = `...`
```

Read [this section of the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) for more info.

Comment: You shouldn't have to splat `prevState` when using `setState`, because react does that for you, iirc... (unless you want to overwrite `urlParams` with the previous value if it is set...)